# Running bash script with for cycle as a Python subprocess in background

Tags: bash, python-2.7, unix, background, subprocess

I have a bash script with a for cycle in it called `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n > "/path/output.txt"
for i  in {1..10}
do 
echo "Test" >> "/path/output.txt"
done
```

I would like to run it in background while the instruction of the Python script are performed.
I am using Python `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('test.sh')
```

I can't get any output or the output is written in "output.txt" only once.

Comment: Your she-bang is wrong, it should have be `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: You probably also want `echo -n ""` or something, unless you want a literal `-n` written to that file. If you just want to create the file, try `touch`.

Comment: @meatspace if I use touch I can't overwrite the file if it is already exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, don't use brace expansions with loops. The shell has to expand the entire expression before you can iterate over it. Either use a C-style `for` loop (in shells like `bash` that support it):

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
    ...
done
```

or use a `while` loop (in any POSIX-compatible shell):

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
    ...
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: Sorry: while [ $i -le 10] do i=$(( $i + 1)).  Ok, I guess they are both rigtht

Comment: The arguments can only be integers in an arithmetic context, so identifiers are automatically dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..10}
```

is not valid syntax for `sh`. You tagged you question with Bash, so replace the first line with

```
#!/bin/bash
```